# This door cannot be open or opened right now

Tags: grammar, word-choice

I stumbled into this question. So my guess is either B or C. Which one is the correct answer?

My interpretation:

> If “open” is a verb, then C would be correct. Otherwise B would be correct when it’s an adjective.

Any ideas?

[image: question]

Comment: They're all correct given the right context.

Comment: I guess they probably want you to answer 'C', but, as @gotube says, you could make a valid sentence with all four options.

Comment: Ha ha, it  is common to see one of these MC questions with 2 legitimate answer, but it rare to see one in which *everything* is possible!  What is the exact source of this test question?

Comment: This is a question from a junior high school exam. The "correct" answer they want you to pick was indeed **C** since that's how the text book was written in that chapter. But it is good to know that those choices are all correct given the right context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @gotube points out, all answers make a valid sentence. Here are some examples:

> "This door cannot **open** right now, because Jake has locked it" (the door is unable or not permitted to move into an open state)

> "We need to keep the room secure! This door cannot **be open** right now, close it immediately" (the door is not permitted to be in an open state)

> "This door cannot **be opened** right now, because the glass in it is being replaced." (the door is unable or not permitted to be moved into an open state by something or someone)

> "I don't believe my eyes! We barricaded it with five planks, this door *cannot* **be opening** right now" (the door is currently moving into an open state, but shouldn't be)